# Is there a way to show a multiselect list box as combobox(single select) but on opening should give multi select

Tags: html, css, multi-select

I am looking for a way where multi select list box should display as normal single select combobox but on click it should work as list box allowing multi selct like show below as in spreadsheet. I am looking for solution in CSS HTML and javascript rather than in Jquery.

[image]

Comment: If you want to make it cross-browser compatible (especially older IEs) it would be silly to stick to pure JS. Using libraries for that is a good solution, is there any reason you might not want to use them?

http://filamentgroup.com/dwpe/ shows some ideas which you might find useful

Comment: The only reason for not using it is, just for this we need to go Jquery so far we managed it with YUI and custum scripts.and posibly this will be only instance we would be using it.:-(

Answer (score 0):

You can't make an element behave like that, but you can make something that looks like a dropdown list, and when the user clicks on it, display a popup/popout with a select that allows multiselect (has the `size` property set).

Answer (score -1):

you can do this by [jQuery MultiSelect](http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/04/jquery-multiselect/) and here is the [demo](http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-multiSelect/demo/)